# Intergration Jira (cloud) with Gitlab (server)

Tags: gitlab, jira

I try to integrate Jira (Cloud) with GitLab (server).
I do everything as instructed https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/integrations/jira.html
If I press "`Test settings and save`", I see "`Test failed. Save anyway`".

My settings

[image: http://dl3.joxi.net/drive/2018/08/20/0000/0105/105/05/a32e24022a.png]

What's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

If you are running self-hosted GitLab server and you require a proxy to get out to the internet you may need to set proxy variables in `/etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb`.  Something like:

```
gitlab_rails['env'] = {"https_proxy" => "https://<MY-PROXY-SERVER>:<MY-PROXY_PORT>"}
gitlab_rails['env'] = {"no_proxy" => "localhost,127.0.0.1,<OTHER-NO-PROXY-ADDRESSES>"}
```

Answer (score 0):

See [GitLab 15.7](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2022/12/22/gitlab-15-7-released/#self-managed-support-for-the-gitlab-for-jira-cloud-app) (December 2022) should simplify the integration, but **for self-managed GitLab only**:

> ### Self-managed support for the GitLab for Jira Cloud app
>
> For self-managed GitLab, we’re excited to announce support for the [GitLab for Jira Cloud app](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/apps/1221011/gitlab-com-for-jira-cloud?tab=overview&hosting=cloud)!
>
> With this release, you can link your self-managed GitLab instance to Jira Cloud and enable the [Jira development panel](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/integration/jira/development_panel.html). This feature supports syncing updates from smart commits, merge requests, branches, builds, deploys, and feature flags back into the Jira development panel. You can pair the GitLab for Jira Cloud app with your [basic Jira integration](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/integration/jira/configure.html).
>
> For more information, see [Connect the GitLab for Jira Cloud app for self-managed instances](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/integration/jira/connect-app.html#connect-the-gitlabcom-for-jira-cloud-app-for-self-managed-instances).
>
> If you use Jira Server or Jira Data Center, you should use the [Jira DVCS Connector](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/integration/jira/dvcs.html).
>
> [image: https://about.gitlab.com/images/15_7/jira_cloud_app_proxy_for_selfmanaged_gitlab_users.png -- Self-managed support for the GitLab for Jira Cloud app]
>
> See [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/integration/jira/connect-app.html#connect-the-gitlabcom-for-jira-cloud-app-for-self-managed-instances) and [Epic](https://gitlab.com/groups/gitlab-org/-/epics/5650).

---

[GitLab 15.11](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2023/04/22/gitlab-15-11-released/#improved-data-sync-between-jira-and-gitlab-for-jira-cloud-app) (April 2023) adds, both for GitLab.com and self-hosted GitLab:

> ### Improved data sync between Jira and GitLab for Jira Cloud app
>
> In GitLab 15.11, we have improved syncing of both existing and new data between Jira Cloud and the GitLab for Jira Cloud app.
>
> Previously, when you added a namespace to the GitLab for Jira Cloud app, only existing merge request data was synced to Jira.
> Now, existing branch and commit data is also synced.
>
> When you viewed a Jira issue, the GitLab for Jira Cloud app previously showed related GitLab branches only if the branch name contained the Jira issue ID (for example, `my-branch-JIRA-1`).
> The GitLab for Jira Cloud app now also links to GitLab branches when you mention the Jira issue ID in the merge request title or description.
>
> See [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/integration/jira/development_panel.html#information-displayed-in-the-panel), [Issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/354373) and [Issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/354371).